# Is changing a parameter from dynamic to object a breaking change?

Tags: c#, .net-core, c#-5.0

In a public library There are some public methods that have `dynamic` parameters like

`public void DoSomething(dynamic date)`

There is no real need for these parameters to be dynamic so I would like to change them into 'object'

`public void DoSomething(object date)`

Is there any way where changing a (input) parameter from dynamic into object could break existing code using this api?

Edit: This question is specifically about breaking an existing consumer of an API when changing the type of the parameter from dynamic to object, not a general question about the difference between the two.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dynamic keyword vs object data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5523031/dynamic-keyword-vs-object-data-type) and [What is the difference between “dynamic” and “object” keywords in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20995759/what-is-the-difference-between-dynamic-and-object-keywords-in-c)

Comment: At first glance, it is as if you were thinking of changing `double` by `int` or `string` by `byte[]`. But it depends of what is done withe the parameter. Normally you should no longer be able to compile.

Comment: @OlivierRogier I doubt the duplicates apply, and that it matters what is done with the argument. The question is whether `dynamic` is assignment-compatible with `object`; the answer should be yes at the source code level, but the already compiled libraries should break.

Comment: Yes, it is [officially](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/#members) a breaking change ("*❌ DISALLOWED: Changing the type of a property, field, parameter, or return value*").

Comment: @GSerg It should not work unless using parameter as object, but why dynamic? Example: `DoProcess(new MyClassA());` | `static void DoProcess(dynamic instance) { instance.MyMethod(); }` | `class MyClassA { public void MyMethod() {; } }`.

Comment: The question is pretty objective: _Is changing a parameter from dynamic to object a breaking change?_ The answer is **yes**

Comment: @.GSerg & @.RodrigoRodrigues Not necessarily. Example: `static void DoProcess(dynamic instance) { Console.WriteLine(instance.ToString()); }`. Changing to `object` here is not breaking, but as written, why originally `dynamic`? There must be some reason, thus *probably breaking*... Hence the suggested duplicates and the comment because I thought the most important was understanding the dynamic typing to understand the answer.

Comment: @GSerg: unless the OP is writing the API for .NET, the article you reference is not binding. It's simply Microsoft's _opinion_ about what _they_ consider a breaking change (and it's not really even relevant, because they don't have any API methods that have `dynamic` as a parameter type, so you can't extrapolate from that document even what _Microsoft_ would consider reasonable).

Comment: _"Is there any way where changing a (input) parameter from dynamic into object could break existing code using this api?"_ -- doubtful. The `dynamic` type _is_ essentially `object`, just with implications for late-binding/runtime-compilation. _Callers_ won't be affected at all...the method itself could even cast the `object` parameter back to `dynamic` to get the late-binding if they wanted. But frankly, without more details from you about why you think this _could_ be a breaking change and how exactly the code is used, the question isn't really useful or answerable.

Comment: Is it not hard for the consumers of this api to know what to send in if the parameters are dynamic or object?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I did I little Test and my conclusion is that the client code will not break by just changing the dynamic parameter to object, even without recompiling the client.

I wrote a .Net libarary project with the method

`public static string DoSomething(dynamic date) => "Dynamic:" + date.ToString();`

And in a console App I called it with

`Console.WriteLine(TestClass.DoSomething(new { Text = "Hallo" }));`

and it prints `Dynamic:{ Text = Hallo }`

Then I changed the code in the library into

`public static string DoSomething(object date) => "object:" + date.ToString();`

Without recompiling the Console app I copied the 'object' version of the dll to the console folder and it runs without error printing
`object:{ Text = Hallo }`